# Transcode FROM MPEG-DASH

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, mpeg-dash, decoding

I have an input MPEG-DASH stream and I want to transcode it.
First of all, need to decode it and then route an output to FFmpeg and encode it, but not have any ideas how to decode MPEG-DASH.
 Please advise how to transcode from DASH, any suggestion will be helpfull.

Comment: How's the media packaged?

Comment: @Mulvya I thinks it's mpegts. For example, need to dash transcode from this link: http://irtdashreference-i.akamaihd.net/dash/live/901161/bfs/manifestARD.mpd

Comment: @Mulvya Can you please explain how to determine the media package from MPEG-DASH? If the link, for example, is http://irtdashreference-i.akamaihd.net/dash/live/901161/bfs/manifestARD.mpd